# Google Docs API: List contents at root folder include folders and documents which are shared to me

Tags: c#, google-docs, google-code, google-docs-api

I use google docs API.

I found an url "http://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/folder%3Aroot/contents/" to list all contents at root. But it is not list documents come from another person who has shared to me.

Expected output:
List contents at root folder include folders and documents which are shared to me

Comment: What is the specific question?

Comment: Question: How can i list contents at root folder include folders and documents which are shared to me?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full" will give you all files and folders in "my drive" and also in "my shared docs"

This will give you just my-shared-docs files and folders:  https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/-/-mine?showfolders=true"

This will give you just my drive files and folders: